# Styling a salutation

Tags: html, css, layout, semantics

I am having a mental block!!

1. is "Dear Sir" known as a salutation? I think this is what my css class will be called
2. Semantically speaking, should the salutation be a `span`, `p` or something else completely!

I'm leaning towards `span`, but wondered if anyone else had a spare 2 cents.

Many thanks

Comment: how does it have to look? could you provide an example?

Comment: @KeesSonnema - Like a letter.  "Dear Sir," new line etc

Comment: You may ask a linguist, what the semantic parts of a letter are. The question is, is the salutation part of the header, part of the first paragraph or part of neither of both.

Comment: im going to take a punt on "part of the first paragraph" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `<span>` for an inline element.

Also, how about trying the [`:first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line) pseudo-element? It will style the first line of a paragraph (assuming your salutation is the first line). For example:

```
p:first-line {
    font-size: 120%;
}
```

[Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating that](http://jsfiddle.net/YTJWt/)

Comment: I had a look at the jsfiddle, good call on the pseudo.  The app im building is mutli-lingual so im storing all text in config files as strings.  so far, i have not mixed content and markup.  the solution in the fiddle would involve mixing text and markup.  i dont think the new line can be added another way.  I was planning a span followed by a p for the content

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ - hmm good browser support too for the pseudo..

Comment: Just bear in mind that this will style literally the first line, so if your salutation wraps over to the second line, it will not be styled. However salutations are usually short, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: so, im using handlebars templates which allow me to safely parse the markup in a string.  the jsfiddle you provided is spot on.  many thanks.  the salutation is short enough to be the first line on a mobile, even in german!! job done

Answer (score 1):

There is no semantics in HTML markup in the sense that some element would mean “the meaning of this element is a salutation”. What is commonly called “semantics” is about structure. And a salutation is not a structural concept; it may appear at the start of a paragraph, or as a paragraph of its own, and maybe even as a heading in some rare cases.

Thus, the natural approach is to use markup that has the desired default rendering. That way, the page appearance is what you want, as far as possible, even when styling is disabled.

For a salutation that is to appear on a line of its own, use `div` if no spacing above or below is desired. Use `p` to get an empty line above and below. And use `span` (or other inline markup, such as `i` or `b`, if italics or bolding is desirable) if the salutation appears at the start of a paragraph, without any line break. Or don’t use any markup, if you have no need to deal with the salutation as an element:

```
<p>Dear Sir, thank you...</p>
```

You may assign a class to the salutation, but this is useful only if you use the class somewhere. A `class` attribute does not describe meaning, though it may suggest one to a person who reads the markup.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a span element as it defaults to an in-line element with no style change.
This is basically what the `<span>` tag [page on w3schools says](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp).
You can then style it to your liking.

Comment: Don't recommend going to w3schools

Comment: Huh, why is this? Back in the day that was the first page I referred to when I needed some info on CSS or HTML.

Comment: @MMM - what resource can you recommend?

Comment: @MMM - ok, i use these for js but never really thought about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML ill have a rummage